# Publishing Jersey service instance to Grizzly

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, grizzly

I can publish a jersey service to grizzly by doing the following

```
final String baseUri = "http://localhost:51000";
final Map<String, String> initParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
initParams.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "my.rest.service");
SelectorThread threadSelector = GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create(baseUri, initParams);
```

So the specified package will be scanned for any service classes annotated with `@Path`, and they will be initialized. My question is, is there any way to specify a pre-initialized jersey service class - initialied via a custom factory or even just by doing new MyService() - and publish it to Grizzly or any other container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GrizzlyServerFactory.create(URI u, ResourceConfig rc) and add your singletons to provided ResourceConfig. ie:

```
final String baseUri = "http://localhost:51000";
final ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("my.rest.service");
rc.getSingletons().add(new MyInstantiatedResource());
SelectorThread threadSelector = GrizzlyServerFactory.create(baseUri, rc);
```

Answer (score 1):

> or any other container?

Jersey also supports the SimpleHttp container, if you add the add-on jersey module and use [SimpleServerFactory](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/contribs/jersey-simple-server/com/sun/jersey/simple/container/SimpleServerFactory.html).

```
ResourceConfig config = new DefaultResourceConfig();
config.getSingletons().add(new MyInstantiatedResource());

String serverBase = "http://localhost:8080/foo";
Closeable server = SimpleServerFactory.create(serverBase, config);
```