# JAX-RS with Protocol Buffers tutorial application

Tags: java, rest, jersey, protocol-buffers, grizzly

I am looking into REST and protocol buffers atm.
Therefore I found [this][1] tutorial which creates a sample application

Unfortunately Ive got a problem with the libraries to import I cant resolve:

In this line:

```
return GrizzlyServerFactory.create(uri, initParams);
```

I am getting a syntax error:

```
The method create(URI, ResourceConfig) in the type
GrizzlyServerFactory is not applicable for the arguments (URI,
Map<String,String>)
```

GrizzlyServerFactory is in this library which I have imported:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.container.grizzly.GrizzlyServerFactory;
```

For reference I am pasting the whole class here:

```
package com.sampullara.jaxrsprotobuf.tutorial;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

import com.sun.grizzly.http.SelectorThread;
import com.sun.jersey.api.container.grizzly.GrizzlyServerFactory;
import com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig;

public class Main {
    public static final URI BASE_URI = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(9998).build();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Starting grizzly...");
        URI uri = BASE_URI;
        SelectorThread threadSelector = createServer(uri);
        System.out.println(String.format("Try out %sperson\nHit enter to stop it...", uri));
        System.in.read();
        threadSelector.stopEndpoint();
    }

    public static SelectorThread createServer(URI uri) throws IOException {
        Map<String, String> initParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        initParams.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "com.sampullara");

        // error happens in next line - constructor doesnt exist with the given parameters
        return GrizzlyServerFactory.create(uri, initParams);
    }
}
```

EDIT1:

Ive modified the code but still cant get it working:

```
public static SelectorThread createServer(URI uri) throws IOException {
    //Map<String, String> initParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    //initParams.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "com.sampullara");
    // original code: return GrizzlyServerFactory.create(uri, initParams);

    DefaultResourceConfig rscfg = new DefaultResourceConfig();
    return GrizzlyServerFactory.create( uri , rscfg );
}
```

Eclipse throws the following runtime error at me:

> SCHWERWIEGEND: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root
>   resource classes. Exception in thread "main"
>   com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig
>   instance does not contain any root resource classes.  at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1300)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:163)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:769)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:172)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:134)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.container.grizzly.GrizzlyServerFactory.create(GrizzlyServerFactory.java:151)
>     at
>   com.sampullara.jaxrsprotobuf.tutorial.Main.createServer(Main.java:34)
>     at com.sampullara.jaxrsprotobuf.tutorial.Main.main(Main.java:21)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`GrizzlyServerFactory.create`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.1.5/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/container/grizzly/GrizzlyServerFactory.html#create%28java.net.URI,%20com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig%29) takes two parameter:

1. `java.net.URI`
2. [`com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.1.5/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceConfig.html)

Using `Map<String, String>` as the second parameter is wrong.

See [Publishing Jersey service instance to Grizzly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306198/publishing-jersey-service-instance-to-grizzly) for another question dealing with `GrizzlyServerFactory`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I ve already seen, that the used constructor is not valid but unfortunately I have no clue on how to modify the code in order to get it working (see first post)